# When I use navigator.language it gives undefined (nodejs)

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I want to find out the default language used by the user visiting my page but the navigator.language is giving undefined, I have installed navigator by writing, "npm i navigator" and it has appeared in my package.json file as "navigator": "^1.0.1"

this is my dropdown.js file

```
   const express= require('express');
   const window= require('window');
   const navigator= require('navigator');
   const { appendFile } = require('fs');
   const port= process.env.PORT || 5000;
   const dropdown=express();
   const dns = require('dns');
   dropdown.use(express.json());
   dropdown.use(express.urlencoded());
   dropdown.use(express.static('public'));

   dropdown.get('/form',(req,res)=>{
   res.sendFile(__dirname + '/dropdown.html'); 
   }  
   )   
   dropdown.post('/form',(req,res)=>{
   console.log(req.body);
   let lang = req.body.dropdown;
   const mapper = {
   "Hindi" : () => res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/hindi.html'),
   "English" : () => res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/english.html'),
   "Japanese": () => res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/japanese.html'),
   }

   var usrlang = navigator.language ;
   console.log("User's preferred language is: "+ usrlang);

   mapper[lang]() })
   dropdown.listen(port,()=>{
   console.log('server started at http://localhost:${port}')
   });
```

this is a section of my html code

```
  <h2>Welcome to the Form</h2>
  <form method="post" action="/form"> 
    <select name = "dropdown" > 
      <option value = "Hindi" selected>Hindi</option> 
      <option value = "English" >English</option> 
      <option value = "Japanese" >Japanese</option> </select>
      <p>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
     </p>
  </form>
```

[this is the output i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGX47.png)

Comment: have you read [any documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/navigator) I don't see any language there - last published 11 years ago - author moved it to a self hosted git repo 5 years ago ... and that server is **dead**

Comment: Oh, and if it did work, that would be the preferred language of the SERVER, not the user - you may be able to determine the users preferred language from the `Accept-Language` request header - though, the preferred language would NEVER be `Hindi`, `English` or `Japanese` .... it'd be something like `en` or `en-GB` or `en-AU` or `jp-jp` or `hi-hi` maybe

Comment: my mistake - it'd be `hi` or `hi-IN` for Hindi and `ja` or `ja-JP` for Japanese - once you get the language, you can simply `language.substring(0,2)` to get just the language without the extra country code